# i have error with install gmapping

Tags: ros, slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

its give me idont have two backage and idont found it  can you help me

ksam@ksam-K53SC:~$ sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall python-rosdep ros-indigo-brown-remotelab ros-indigo-control ros-indigo-common-msgs ros-indigo-slam-gmapping ros-indigo-hector-slam Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-brown-remotelab E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-control

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199903/i-have-error-with-install-gmapping/) by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot install brown-remotelab for Indigo as it has not been released for indigo: http://wiki.ros.org/brown_remotelab It lookslike the most recent release was in Groovy.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0